# Why am I getting an out of index error on my matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm currently trying to make code for a game, the game is a lot like checkers. I'm representing my board as a 10 x 10 matrix. There exist two ways of moving in this game, you can do a step where you check all the positions adjacent to you and if any of them is empty you can move into them. Then if the position right next to you is occupied but the space right next to that space is empty you can hop on top of the player occupying said spot. So far I have three important pieces of code to finish my game. My first piece of code is the board, the second piece of code is two variables each one contains a list of the coordinates of each player's chips and the third part is two functions, one that allows me to hop and the other one that allows me to do steps.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],  #0 this is the board, it's represented by a 10x10 matrix
                   [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],  #1 the 0s represent empty spaces
                   [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  #2 the 1s represent player 1's chips
                   [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  #3 the 2s represetn player 2's chips
                   [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  #4 
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],  #5
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2],  #6
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2],  #7
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2],  #8
                   [0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2]]) #9

chips1 = list(tuple(map(tuple,np.fliplr(np.argwhere(matrix == 1))))) #Finds all the positions that contain a 1
chips2 = list(tuple(map(tuple,np.fliplr(np.argwhere(matrix == 2))))) #Finds all the positions that contain a 2

print chips2

def step(x,y): #Finds the possible steps for a checker
    listMoves = []
    if x > 0 and matrix[x-1][y] == 0: #left
        listMoves.append([x-1,y])
    if x < 9 and matrix[x+1][y] == 0: #right
        listMoves.append([x+1,y])
    if y < 9: #up
        if matrix[x][y+1] == 0:
            listMoves.append([x,y+1])
        if x>0 and matrix[x-1][y+1] == 0: #up + left
            listMoves.append([x-1,y+1])
        if x < 9 and matrix[x+1][y+1] == 0: #up + right
            listMoves.append([x+1,y+1])
    if y > 0: #down
        if matrix[x][y-1] == 0:
            listMoves.append([x,y-1])
        if x > 0 and matrix[x-1][y-1] == 0: #down + left
            listMoves.append([x-1,y-1])
        if x<9 and matrix[x+1][y-1] == 0:
            listMoves.append([x+1,y-1])
    return listMoves

def hopper(x,y): #Finds the possible hops for a checker
    listHops = []
    if x > 1 and matrix[x-1][y] != 0 and matrix[x-2][y] == 0: #left
        listHops.append([x-2,y])
    if x < 8 and matrix[x+1][y] != 0 and matrix[x+2][y] == 0: #right
        listHops.append([x+2,y])
    if y > 1:
        if matrix[x][y-1] != 0 and matrix[x][y-2] == 0: #down
            listHops.append([x,y-2])
        if x>1 and matrix[x-1][y-1] != 0 and matrix[x-2][y-2] == 0: #down + left
            listHops.append([x-2,y-2])
        if x < 8 and matrix[x+1][y+1] != 0 and matrix[x+2][y-2] == 0: #up + right
            listHops.append([x+2,y-2])
    if y < 8:
        if matrix[x][y+1] != 0 and matrix[x][y+2] == 0: #up
            listHops.append([x,y+2])
        if x > 1 and matrix[x-1][y+1] != 0 and matrix[x-2][y+2] == 0: #up + left
            listHops.append([x-2,y+2])
        if x < 8 and matrix[x+1][y+1] != 0 and matrix[x+2][y+2] == 0: #up + right
            listHops.append([x+2,y+2])
    listHops = listHops + step(x,y)
    return listHops
'''
def flipBoard():
    global matrix 
    matrix = np.fliplr(np.flipud(matrix))
    return matrix.tolist() 
flipBoard()
'''
for i in range(0,len(chips2)): #loops through the list of positions to find all the possible steps and hops for 
    print hopper(chips2[i][0], chips2[i][1])#every single checker on the board
print matrix
```

The for loop is used to go through the list of all my chips and find all the possible moves for all the chips. When I do this with the 1 chips which are at the top left of the board it returns all the possible plays, which are 32 if that's of any use. However when I run this same function with the 2 chips I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-3429014a2777>", line 80, in <module>
    print hopper(chips2[i][0], chips2[i][1])#every single checker on the board

  File "<ipython-input-21-3429014a2777>", line 59, in hopper
    if x < 8 and matrix[x+1][y+1] != 0 and matrix[x+2][y-2] == 0: #up + right

IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10
```

So far I have managed to find out it only happens with hops and it only happens when you're trying to hop to the right. I've tried changing it to x < 7 and x <=8 and it's still not working. On the left side it works perfectly fine. Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening? It's obviously a logic problem on my side but I'm out of ideas as to how I can fix it.

Comment: show the complete traceback.  Also print what I is in the indicated code

Comment: Just edited the question to add the complete traceback. And what do you mean when you ask me to print l?

Comment: I mean print x or y, to see what it is before it fails.  It might give you a clue, but the answer below might be right for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should print values of `x` and `y` in your `hopper` function. Since `chips2` contains indices in the matrix with value 2, then the index `[9][9]` will be contained in `chips2` implying `x = 9` or `y = 9` at some point.

Therefore `matrix[x+1][y+1]` would mean  `matrix[10][10]` which does not exist. You should review your code.

you should do:

```
if x < 8:
    if matrix[x+1][y+1] != 0 and matrix[x+2][y-2] == 0: #up + right
         . . .
```

In that way, you don't perform a check on an index that is out of range

Comment: I tried running it with steps and it works. It's the hops function that's causing the problems. I tried it manually with every single position within my chips2 list of positions. However when I did it with hops I got the problem and it only happens with like 4 out of the 15 chips.

Comment: The 4 indices `(x, y) = (8,8), (8,9) (9,8) (9,9)` would fail on `matrix[x+1][y]` or `matrix[x+2][y]`. See my update on how to test items in your matrix

Comment: I ran it like this: 
step(chips2[8][0],chips2[8][1])
And it does return values. I hope I'm not misunderstanding you or that you're misunderstanding me, but if I'm correct you're trying to fix my step functions which hasn't given me any problems when what I really need to fix is the hop function. Please correct me if I'm wrong? Also thank you for taking some time to help me.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I still think cascading your `if` condition on `right` will help. See my new update.

Comment: Just tried it out and I keep getting the same problem. :(

Comment: From, your code, you have up and right replicated in two places. Did you update both of them with an intial check on `x`? And one of them should read down and right. You can update your question with the updated code.

Comment: Ok I tested your solution. It worked, however I commented out the pieces of code that check when you try to hop to the right side and to the bottom right. I guess I could fix bottom right by doing what I did on top right but instead of checking y < 8 I check y > 1. However how can I fix the hop when I just want to move to the right?

Comment: For right, the condition `if x<8:` should enclose the other `if`

Comment: Hey, I tested your solution, I pulled the if x > 8 from the right condition and it worked. I also pulled out the if x < 8 and y < 8: out of the up right. And it works. However when I try the if x < 8 and y > 1 for the down right it gives me the out of index error. Should I just pull x < 8 instead of pulling out both x < 8 and y > 1?

Comment: Ok only down right isn't working, I pulling the x<8 into an outer if and it didn't work.

Comment: Ok never mind it works. I'm really grateful for all the time you spent helping me out. Really appreciate it. The reason why the down right wasn't working is explained on the other answer. I had a typo where I checked the x+1 and y+1 where not equal to zero but it was supposed to be y-1 instead. Again thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
if x < 8 and matrix[x+1][y+1] != 0 and matrix[x+2][y-2] == 0: #up + right
#                         ^ typo - that's down, not up
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not only is the sign a typo but the comment is also a typo, the cocommen is supposed to be #up + down. Thanks for the help.